# Set two values in one matrix

Tags: c#

Is it possible to set two values in one `for` loop? I would like to create a string matrix [,], the first element (i) is variable, the second (j) is constant

```
int rowRun = 1;
string[,] costume = new string [elementsOfRunning, rowRun];

int columnRun = costume.GetLength(0);
for (int i = 0; i < columnRun; i++)
{
    int rowOfRunning;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row of running (0-42)");
        rowOfRunning = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    while (!(0 <= rowOfRunning && rowOfRunning <= 42));
    string rowOfRunning2 = rowOfRunning.ToString();
}
```

And here I would like to set the `i` value for example: `costume[i,j] = rowOfRunning;` But I can't in this way.

```
for (int j = 0; j < rowRun; j++)
{
    string comment = "";
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a comment: („verseny”, „terep”, „laza”, „fartlek”, „résztáv”");
        comment = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while (!comment.Contains(",") && comment != "verseny" && comment != "terep" && comment != "laza" && comment != "fartlek" && comment != "résztáv");                   

    costume[i, j] = comment;                 
    Console.WriteLine(costume[i,j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do but you can declare more than one variable in for loop like this:

```cs
var array = new Array[10, 10];

for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < 3; j++, i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("i:" + i + " j:" + j);
    array[i,j] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```